# как удалить из массива повторяющиеся элементы js

Tags: javascript

```
var x=[55,44,55,30,30]=>[55,44,30]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = [55, 44, 55, 30, 30];
for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (x.indexOf(x[i]) != i)
    x.splice(i, 1);
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
let x = [55, 44, 55, 30, 30]
let unique = [...new Set(x)]

console.log(unique)
```

или

```js
let x = [55, 44, 55, 30, 30]
let unique = x.filter((e, i) => x.indexOf(e) === i )

console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = [55, 44, 55, 30, 30];
var y = [];
x.forEach(function(el, i) {
  if (y.indexOf(el) === -1) {
    y.push(el);
  }
})
console.log(y);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```